# How to fix apk not installed error in fortnite apk?

Tags: application-error

I am trying to install Fortnite on my phone. But it's saying the app is not installed. I tried on a few other phones too. It is not installing on any device I tried, but they all are actually incompatible for Fortnite. Even if it's not supported, why is it not installing? I can see many incompatible APKs installing on my device well. Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: According to what I have read Fortine requires an Android 64 bit OS. If your devices are all 32bit means they simply can't execute the app, because an 32bit OS can't run 64bit software (may be even your CPU does not support 64bit).

Comment: Robert, One of the devices i checked was a 64-bit device. It almost had all requirements to run fortnite except the ram. It had only 2 gb ram. But its not installing in too.Help!